# How can I add custom pulse gate to the Qiskit circuit?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I tried to make my pulse and get the pulse into the circuit. But it seems not working properly.
The code and the result are below.

[image]

[image: test as X gate]

[image: test as X gate]

Just change the 'x' to the 'h' (hadamard) with the same piecewise pulse, I get the result below.
[image]

I used same pulse but just the label of gate made different results. I think the pulse I made didn't link to the circuit.
How can I link the self-calibrated pulse to the circuit?

Comment: Are you transpiling your circuit before running it, if so you'll have to supply an update list of basis_gates to the transpiler so that it doesn't use the backend's normal gateset? Is this a real backend or a simulator?

Comment: I didn't transpile the circuit at all. And the backend is FakeArmonk.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a bug with the fake backend's recognizing that calibrations were supplied and to use the pulse simulator instead. Could you try submitting the circuit manually to the pulse simulator? See https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/10_pulse_simulator_backend_model.html